# 'Jupyter' cmd NOT found in terminal in MacOS, but I cannot launch the notebook via Pycharm

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I used Pycharm to write python code, also, I installed in Jupyter via pip3 in the terminal. When I type 'jupyter notebook', cmd NOT found. but I can launch the notebook in Pycharm. I think this is a path problem. but I have no idea what to do.

Anyone have any solution? Thanks

Comment: It does sound like a PATH issue. Try to work out where the `jupyter` command got installed to.